# Proving that product of difference ideal (left-right ideal) is subset of their intersection as follows.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring, $I$ and $J$ be the right and left ideals, respectively.
Prove that $IJ \subseteq I \cap J$.

My attempt:

Let $x \in IJ$. That is, $x = i_1j_1+i_2j_2+\dots + i_nj_n$, for all $i_k \in I, j_k \in J, 1\leq k \leq n, n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Now, if $i_k \in I, \sum_{k=1}^{n} i_kj_k \in I$ and if $j_k \in J, \sum_{k=1}^{n} i_kj_k \in J$. Hence, $x = I \cap J \Leftrightarrow IJ \subseteq I \cap J$.

As above, may I assume that if $i_k \in I, j_k \in R$ and if $j_k \in J, i_k \in R$ ?

Please correct me if I got mistake way in proving. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I think you mean $I$ is *a* left ideal not *the* left ideal, similarly $J$, and $x=i_1j_1+\dots+i_nj_n$ for *some* $i_k\in I$, $j_k\in J$, not *all* $i_k\in I$, $j_k\in J$.  Anyway,  since $I,J\subseteq R$, you definitely can say $i_k,j_k\in R$.

Comment: So, my answer above is correct or not ?

Comment: Anyway, thanks for correction!

Comment: Why do you need to talk about elements at all?  Isn't it obvious $IJ\subseteq I$ because $I$ is a right ideal, and $IJ\subseteq J$ since $J$ is a left ideal?